# What is empty operator?

Tags: java, netbeans

What does **"empty operator"** warning (translated from russian) mean in netbeans?

```
for(int v = 1; v <= n; v++) {
            int parent = in.nextInt();
            if(parent == 0);
                root = v;
        }
```

Comment: You should remove ';' after if(parent == 0) condition, as suggested in the answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an unnecessary and dangerous semicolon(;) that changes your program flow in the row where the warning pops.

The semicolon is an empty statement, hence `root = v` will always execute regardless of whether `parent == 0` or not.

Comment: The semicolon is not useless, it's positively dangerous...as it is actually changing the program behaviour. This sort of thing is one reason it's always recommended to use {} around the parts of an if statement.